redis connection Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis on nodeJs server
I'm using nodeJs as a server and while trying to init redist connection i got this error:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis 2024-11-17 13:32:35     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) { 2024-11-17 13:32:35   errno: -3008, 2024-11-17 13:32:35   code: 'ENOTFOUND', 2024-11-17 13:32:35   syscall: 'getaddrinfo', 2024-11-17 13:32:35   hostname: 'redis' 2024-11-17 13:32:35 }

i'm running the server on Docker using docker compose.
nodeJs redis init file - i'm using redis "^4.7.0" and node v18.12.0, i run this function inside the
app.listen(port, () => { // call redisInit here!})

:
import { createClient, RedisClientType } from "redis";
let redisClient: RedisClientType;  
export const redisInit = () => {      
    redisClient = createClient({        
        socket: { port: 6379, host: "redis" },      
    });      
    redisClient.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis client error: ", err));
    redisClient.connect().then(async () => {        
        console.log("Redis connected");      
    });  
}

and this is the docker compose:
services:   
    my-service:     
    container_name: my-service     
    build:       
        context: .       
        dockerfile: Dockerfile     
    ports:
        - 5000:5000    
     depends_on:      
         - redis     
    links:       
        - redis     
    environment:       
        REDIS_HOST: redis      
         REDIS_PORT: 6379   
    redis:     
    container_name: redis     
    hostname: redis     
    image: "redis/redis-stack:edge"     
    ports:       
        - 6379:6379       
        - 8001:8001     
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]     
    environment:       
        REDIS_ARGS: "--notify-keyspace-events Ksg"     
    deploy:       
        replicas: 1       
        restart_policy:         
            condition: on-failure    
     networks:       
        - app-network # Attach Redis to the shared network 
networks:   
    app-network:     
        external: true

i have try to change the connection "createClient" via url or socket. and also try the host as "localhost" or "0.0.0.0", but didn't work for me.
i add image from window docker that show that redis is up
redis docker picture

The two containers aren't on the same networks:.  The easiest solution is to delete all of the networks: blocks in the whole file; Compose will create a network named default for you.  You should also delete the obsolete links: option, and probably also the unnecessary container_name: and hostname: overrides.

@DavidMaze i did change like you said, but now i got SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly
